# Get properties and values from unknown object

Tags: c#, reflection

From the world of PHP I have decided to give C# a go. I've had a search but can't seem to find the answer of how to do the equivalent to this.

```
$object = new Object();

$vars = get_class_vars(get_class($object));

foreach($vars as $var)
{
    doSomething($object->$var);
}
```

I basically have a List of an object. The object could be one of three different types and will have a set of public properties. I want to be able to get a list of the properties for the object, loop over them and then write them out to a file.
I'm thinking this has something to do with c# reflection but it's all new to me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As a side note: having objects of different types in a list (without a common base class or interface) is not a good programming style, at least not in c#.

Answer (score 350, accepted):

This should do it:

```
Type myType = myObject.GetType();
IList<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>(myType.GetProperties());

foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
{
    object propValue = prop.GetValue(myObject, null);

    // Do something with propValue
}
```

Comment: where does PropertyInfo comes from?

Comment: @jonathan `System.Reflection` namespace

Comment: There is no really need to create a list from array, simply `PropertyInfo[] props = input.GetType().GetProperties();`

Comment: Do you want to update for the 2017 answer using `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert`?

Comment: @clone that's a completely different way of doing it. You should post an answer if you think it's a valid approach

Comment: Here in almost 2019 I'd just cast it to a `dynamic`

Comment: @Jonesopolis how can you get properties from a `dynamic` without first casting it to an `object` and then doing the same as in my answer?

Answer (score 42):

```
void Test(){
    var obj = new{a="aaa", b="bbb"};

    var val_a = obj.GetValObjDy("a"); //="aaa"
    var val_b = obj.GetValObjDy("b"); //="bbb"
}
//create in a static class
static public object GetValObjDy(this object obj, string propertyName)
{            
     return obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(obj, null);
}
```

Answer (score 22):

One line solution using Linq...

```cs
var obj = new {Property1 = 1, Property2 = 2};
var property1 = obj.GetType().GetProperties().First(o => o.Name == "Property1").GetValue(obj , null);
```

Answer (score 21):

Yes, Reflection would be the way to go.  First, you would get the [`Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?view=net-6.0) that represents the type (at runtime) of the instance in the list.  You can do this by calling the [`GetType` method on `Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gettype?view=net-6.0).  Because it is on the `Object` class, it's callable by *every* object in .NET, as all types derive from `Object` ([well, technically, not everything](https://web.archive.org/web/20151021062014/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/06/not-everything-derives-from-object.aspx), but that's not important here).

Once you have the `Type` instance, you can call the [`GetProperties` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties?view=net-6.0) to get the [`PropertyInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo?view=net-6.0) instances which represent the run-time informationa about the properties on the `Type`.

Note, you can use the overloads of `GetProperties` to help classify *which* properties you retrieve.

From there, you would just write the information out to a file.

Your code above, translated, would be:

```
// The instance, it can be of any type.
object o = <some object>;

// Get the type.
Type type = o.GetType();

// Get all public instance properties.
// Use the override if you want to classify
// which properties to return.
foreach (PropertyInfo info in type.GetProperties())
{
    // Do something with the property info.
    DoSomething(info);
}
```

Note that if you want method information or field information, you would have to call the one of the overloads of the [`GetMethods`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmethods?view=net-6.0) or [`GetFields`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getfields?view=net-6.0) methods respectively.

Also note, it's one thing to list out the members to a file, but you *shouldn't* use this information to drive logic based on property sets.

Assuming you have control over the implementations of the types, you should derive from a common base class or implement a common interface and make the calls on those (you can use the [`as`](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55979) or [`is`](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55979) operator to help determine which base class/interface you are working with at runtime).

However, if you don't control these type definitions and have to drive logic based on pattern matching, then that's fine.

Answer (score 18):

well, in C# it's similar.
Here's one of the simplest examples (only for public properties):

```
var someObject = new { .../*properties*/... };
var propertyInfos = someObject.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo pInfo in propertyInfos)
{
    string propertyName = pInfo.Name; //gets the name of the property
    doSomething(pInfo.GetValue(someObject,null));
}
```

Answer (score 11):

To get specific property value from property name

```
public class Bike{
public string Name {get;set;}
}

Bike b = new Bike {Name = "MyBike"};
```

to access property value of Name from string name of property

```
public object GetPropertyValue(string propertyName)
{
//returns value of property Name
return this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(this, null);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use *GetType - GetProperties - Linq Foreach*:

```
obj.GetType().GetProperties().ToList().ForEach(p =>{
                                                        //p is each PropertyInfo
                                                        DoSomething(p);
                                                    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's something I use to transform an `IEnumerable<T>` into a `DataTable` that contains columns representing `T`'s properties, with one row for each item in the `IEnumerable`:

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    var table = CreateDataTableForPropertiesOfType<T>();
    PropertyInfo[] piT = typeof(T).GetProperties();
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var dr = table.NewRow();
        for (int property = 0; property < table.Columns.Count; property++)
        {
            if (piT[property].CanRead)
            {
                var value = piT[property].GetValue(item, null);
                if (piT[property].PropertyType.IsGenericType)
                {
                    if (value == null)
                    {
                        dr[property] = DBNull.Value;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dr[property] = piT[property].GetValue(item, null);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    dr[property] = piT[property].GetValue(item, null);
                }
            }
        }
        table.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
    return table;
}

public static DataTable CreateDataTableForPropertiesOfType<T>()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    PropertyInfo[] piT = typeof(T).GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in piT)
    {
        Type propertyType = null;
        if (pi.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
        {
            propertyType = pi.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        }
        else
        {
            propertyType = pi.PropertyType;
        }
        DataColumn dc = new DataColumn(pi.Name, propertyType);

        if (pi.CanRead)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);
        }
    }
    return dt;
}
```

This is "somewhat" overcomplicated, but it's actually quite good for seeing what the outcome is, as you can give it a `List<T>` of, for example:

```
public class Car
{
    string Make { get; set; }
    int YearOfManufacture {get; set; }
}
```

And you'll be returned a DataTable with the structure:

> Make (string) 
>   YearOfManufacture (int)

With one row per item in your `List<Car>`

Answer (score 1):

This example trims all the string properties of an object.

```
public static void TrimModelProperties(Type type, object obj)
{
    var propertyInfoArray = type.GetProperties(
                                    BindingFlags.Public | 
                                    BindingFlags.Instance);
    foreach (var propertyInfo in propertyInfoArray)
    {
        var propValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null);
        if (propValue == null) 
            continue;
        if (propValue.GetType().Name == "String")
            propertyInfo.SetValue(
                             obj, 
                             ((string)propValue).Trim(), 
                             null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found this to work on, say Application objects. I have however had success with

```
var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

string rval = serializer.Serialize(myAppObj);
```

Comment: Don't use JavaScriptSerializer if you can avoid it. [There are great many reasons](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonNetVsDotNetSerializers.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
string[] arr = ((IEnumerable)obj).Cast<object>()
                                 .Select(x => x.ToString())
                                 .ToArray();
```

Once every array implements IEnumerable interface

Answer (score 0):

```
public Dictionary<string, string> ToDictionary(object obj)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    Type objectType = obj.GetType();
    IList<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>(objectType.GetProperties());

    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
    {
        object propValue = prop.GetValue(obj, null);
        dictionary.Add(prop.Name, propValue.ToString());
    }

    return dictionary;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    /// get set value field in object to object new (two object  field like ) 

    public static void SetValueObjectToObject (object sourceObj , object resultObj)
    {
        IList<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>(sourceObj.GetType().GetProperties());
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
        {
            try
            {
                //get value in sourceObj
                object propValue = prop.GetValue(sourceObj, null);
                //set value in resultObj
                PropertyInfo propResult = resultObj.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                if (propResult != null && propResult.CanWrite)
                {
                    propResult.SetValue(resultObj, propValue, null);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {  
                // do something with Ex
            }
        }
    }
```