# LinqPad can not return correct table type

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linqpad

I use LinqPad connect to sql server. There is a standard database Northwind with table Product. I need get the table property information dynamic(read table name from client console input). Unfortunately, LinqPad hide the table real type. What ever how I try, it always return null to me.

please be aware, this question is not same with others. I need get table properties relate to user input table name like "Products". The challenge part is I do not need get string "LINQPad.User.Products" properties, but I do need get the table LINQPad.User.Products properties. The answer for question [Get properties and values from unknown object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144778/get-properties-and-values-from-unknown-object)
can not solve my question. Actually my question is same with that answer, just code format is different.

```
var propertyInfo = (Type.GetType(fullTableName)).GetProperties();
```

---

```
var tableName = Console.ReadLine();
string fullTableName =  "LINQPad.User." + tableName;
var propertyInfo = (Type.GetType(fullTableName)).GetProperties();
```

---

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144778/get-properties-and-values-from-unknown-object

Comment: @DJ KRAZE, the way you ref can get a string "LINQPad.User.Products" properties, but I need get type LINQPad.User.Products properties.

Comment: @paqogomez, "Get properties and values from unknown object" is NOT SAME WITH MY QUESTION!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the properties, you can use something along the lines of this...

```
void Main()
{
    string tableName = Console.ReadLine();

    Type.GetType("UserQuery").GetProperty(tableName)
                             .PropertyType
                             .GenericTypeArguments
                             .First()
                             .GetProperties()
                             .Dump("The properties of the " + tableName + " table");

}
```

Comment: @Thanks Mr. Aydin Adn. You save my life.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
this.GetType().GetProperty("Products").PropertyType.GetProperties().Dump();
```

To test, you can compare it with the following:

```
Products.GetType().GetProperties().Dump();
```

And you get the same results.

Comment: thanks for your answer, the two line code you provide get identical result. but I need the result can be     typeof(Products).GetProperties().Dump(); how to change you code to this?