# C# Trying to access content "member variables" values within a object? (Nullable<object>) instance

Tags: .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022, nullable, nullable-reference-types, c#-10.0

Here is info about our technical development environment :

•   .NET 6

•   C# 10

•   Visual Studio 2022

Here is my code:

> ```
> public class TestEntity
> {
>     public int TestMethod()
>     {
>         object? someObject = new
>         {
>             info_id = "TestItOutInfoId",
>             customer_email_address = lin@newyork.com,
>             subject = "Resolved",
>             sent_date_time = DateTime.Now,
>             sender_email_address = mac@don.com
>        };
>
>         someObject. Blah blah do Not know what method can access the aforementioned properties listed above. BlahBlah
>
>         return 0;
>     }
> }
> ```

[image]

[image]

I could not find anything on the internet that relates to code that will access the content "member variables" within a `Nullable<object>` instance.

Furthermore, in the picture snapshot above, Visual Studio 2022 Intellisense does Not show any helpful methods that will allow me to access said content "member variables"

What code do I need to write that will allow me to access them?

Comment: `object?` is a nullable reference type, which has nothing to do with `Nullable<>` (the latter is only applicable to value types). You're creating an anonymous type. Just use `var` instead of `object?`.

Comment: I can't change from object?  because the variable that is of object? type is part of a 3rd-party software API that I can Not modify.  Could you please advise?

Comment: @Yarik Thx. However, this link will lead to the code solution that helped me:   https://stackoverflow.com/a/4144815/1338998

Comment: I don't get how can you not change the variable type. Looking at the code above, you clearly can.